# How could you find a user's rank by tag and location on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, top-users

How could one find out what their rank is on Stack Overflow by location and keyword/tag? So, to find the top iOS developer in Australia, it could be 'Swift' 'Australia'.

Here is how you find your rank by country using a Stack exchange data explorer query ([query link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/126577/top-users-by-location)):

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Id AS [User Link], 
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    LOWER(Location) LIKE LOWER('%##Location##%')
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

I don't know how to add the tag clause to the query.

Here is an example of how to query on a tag ([link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/52750/tag-rankings-fun)):

```
-- Tag Rankings Fun
-- Put banks in for Tag Name for all. Tag names should be in lower case
-- Put 0 for user ID for all users

DECLARE @tagName varchar(255) 
DECLARE @tagInput bit
SET @tagname = rtrim(##TagName:string##)
DECLARE @UserID int = ##UserId##

IF RTRIM(@tagname) = ''

   SET @tagInput = 0 
ELSE
   SET @tagInput = 1
 
if @tagInput  = 0 and @UserID = 0 
  SELECT 'Don' + '''' + 't do that'
ELSE 
 
WITH UserTagScores
as 
(SELECT  
   a.OwnerUserId,
   t.TagName,
   SUM(CASE v.VoteTypeID
           WHEN 2 THEN 1
           WHEN 3 THEN  -1
   END) as  score

FROM 
   votes v
   INNER JOIN Posts a
   ON v.PostID = a.ID
   INNER JOIN Posts q
   ON a.parentId = q.id
   INNER JOIN PostTags pt
   ON q.id = pt.PostId
   INNER JOIN Tags T
   ON pt.TagId = t.id
WHERE
   v.voteTypeId in (2,3)  -- Up and down votes
   and
   a.PostTypeID = 2  -- Answers only
   AND
   (a.CommunityOwnedDate is null or 
    a.CommunityOwnedDate > v.CreationDate)
   AND 
   (@tagInput = 0
    or t.TagName = @TagName)
    AND a.OwnerUserId is not null
GROUP BY
   a.OwnerUserId,
   t.TagName)
, userTagRank as (
 SELECT
    TagName,
   OwnerUserId,
    rank() over (partition by TagName order by score desc) rank,

Score
  FROM
    UserTagScores)
SELECT 
    TagName,
    Rank,
    OwnerUserId ,
    OwnerUserId [User Link],
    Score
FROM
    userTagRank 
WHERE 
    (OwnerUserId = @UserID or @UserID = 0)
ORDER BY
    TagName,
    rank
```

Comment: Define "tags for a user".

Comment: @Oded I want to find the top ios developers in an area

Comment: OK. How do you define a top iOS developer, given only questions have tags directly associated with them?

Comment: True. I don't know if possible. Was just wondering.

Comment: In an area? Meaning city/country? You can't do that anyway. There is no way to know where a user is. The location field isn't standardized and not required. And they don't have to tell the truth.